# Expo cannot load any images from assets folder

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I have some image file paths that come from a database. The images are located in my `/assets` folder locally. But none of them load.

In my component my render function is basically

```
render(){
    return <Image source={{uri: '/assets/book/cover.png'}}></Image>
}
```

When I inspect the network tab, the image is always 3.5kb and blank, and status is 200 OK. The path looks correct, ie `localhost:1906/assets/book/cover.png`.

I have no idea what to do. I followed [this tutorial](https://docs.expo.dev/tutorial/image/) and it doesn't work either. In this case the image loads but is not displayed anywhere. Regardless I cannot use `import` anyway since the image URI is from a database.

What secret configuration item am I missing to be able to just load images from the `assets` folder?

Answer (score 1):

You have images in your assets folder and stored the paths in your DB. What you can do is to require all your images in a file and store images names instead of their paths in your DB, when you resolve image name from database you can use `<Image source={images[imageName]} .. />`

```js
    // images.js file
    export default images = {
        cover: require('./assets/images/cover.png'),
        avatar: require('./assets/images/avatar-2.png')
    }

    // in your component file
    import images from './images'

    ...
    // use imageName that resolved from database
    // imageName is the same as defined in your images.js file, like cover
    <Image source={images[imageName]} .. />

    ...
```

Comment: What happens if a new image is added?

Comment: Sorry for late answer I didn't notice. I assume that from added you mean downloading new images from internet to users device and then trying to show them in your app. For this you can make use of CameraRoll API which give you access to users photos and videos. [Github repo](https://github.com/react-native-cameraroll/react-native-cameraroll)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use expo-assets? In my case(the project was expo bare workflow), I had to use the useAsssts from expo-assets to download and store the local images locally. You can refer to [this document](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/asset/#useassets)

```
const [assets, error] = useAssets([require('path/to/asset.jpg'), require('path/to/other.png')]);

return assets ? <Image source={assets[0]} /> : null;
```

I hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the image path properly.

Try using like this

```
render()
{
return <Image source={require('/assets/book/cover.png')}/>
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try adding width and height to the image ?

```
render(){
    return <Image source={{uri: '/assets/book/cover.png'}} style={{width: 200 , height: 200 }}/>
}
```

Comment: The issue is that the image itself does not load. This doesn't help unfortunately.